# bin/hadoop no such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I`m trying to install hadoop 2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.
When I write this command line

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'"
```

this is the cmd

```
araziz@araziz-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~$ cd hadoop
araziz@araziz-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/hadoop$ ls
hadoop-2.6.0-src  hadoop-2.6.0-src.tar.gz
araziz@araziz-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/hadoop$ cd ha*
araziz@araziz-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0-src$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
bash: bin/hadoop: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

In all hadoop tutorials, `bin/hadoop` is the location of hadoop, you could see it also as `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop`. `$HADOOP_HOME` it's where hadoop it's located. In my case, it's in `/usr/local/hadoop`. But, again, it depends on the instructions that you are following. Check more closely your tutorial !

Answer (score 0):

Before running Hadoop commands you need to set $HADOOP_HOME in .bashrc file

Comment: Even HADOOP_HOME is necessary (HADOOP_PREFIX in the last versions), to be able to execute hadoop commands, what you need to do is to include the **bin** directory in your PATH or be in the hadoop folder in your terminal to execute the commands relatively to your current path. HADOOP_HOME will be used by hadoop commands but first your terminal should be able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

To help in this situations, I've created some scripts in this repository: https://github.com/lalosam/EasyHadoop.

hadoop.sh script download, unpack, configure hadoop, install required dependencies and set environment variables according with the latest (hadoop 2.7.1) official Getting Started tutorial. I developed it on Linux Mint but it should work in Ubuntu since they are using the same package manager (apt-get).